# Can't drop empty column in DataFrame [Python]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove an empty column from a .csv file that I generate. As can be seen, the first column is empty, I want to remove this but have failed to do so using the pd.drop() feature. Using the pd.info() tells me nothing about the first column. [image: CSV File]

[image: CSV data]

Info simply just shows that "0_x" is the first column, but it for sure isn't. This is the simple code I've used so far for this:

```
def transform_to_test():
    df1 = pd.read_csv('csv-data/testfile.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('csv-data/testlabelfile.csv')

    new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Unnamed: 0', '0']], on='Unnamed: 0', how='left')
    new_df = new_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
    print(new_df.info())
    new_df.to_csv(r'testing.csv')
```

I've tried adding the empty string '' to the drop function, but it produces an error:

> KeyError: "[''] not in index"

Hope you can help

Comment: First column is index, for avoid write to file use `new_df.to_csv(r'testing.csv', index=False)`